# how to validate dates in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datetime, date

I have been having this issue with dates since "ever"

I live in a country where we use the british date formats e.g. dd/mm/yyyy but everytime I try to do a query to a sql db hosted in a US server, 100% of the time I come accross to errors.

`Convert.ToDateTime("2007-17-5")` produces an error where as `Convert.ToDateTime("2007-5-17")` also produces an error.

Many validation methods, many t-sql queries and many other ways I've tried and solved partially in most of my projects however, I would like to know if anyone out there has a  universal way of converting strings to a date that would not cause any problems?

or any good resources regarding working with dates ?

----------- editing... -----------------

even if I format the dates correctly, the query to the sql server doesn not produce any value even if I am sure that there are.. for example.. if I am searching for the records that belongs to dates between 1/1/2009 (that is 1 Jan 2009) through 1/5/2009 (that is 1 MAY 2009) no records are returned. And when I try to change the date in the query builder of the sql server, it gives me an error saying its not a valid date that I am entering...

Comment: "2007-5-17" is not a valid International date, "2007-05-17" is. If you are going to be using the International format "YYYY-MM-DD" you need to include the leading 0s.

Comment: thank you jrcs3, the leading zero was what I was missing... And I am at last glad to find out that there is an international way of working with dates as it gave me enough headache until now...

Comment: Cool, I added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2007-5-17** is not a valid International Date (ISO 8601), **2007-05-17** is. If you are going to be using the International format **CCYY-MM-DD** you need to include the leading **0**s

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date

http://www.saqqara.demon.co.uk/datefmt.htm

Answer (score 3):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) and give some format, that represent your date string

Answer (score 2):

You handle a lot date validation of this in the UI.

First, in your webconfig, you need to set your culture:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

You can use the CompareValidator control on the client side with by setting the Type attribute to "Date".

```
<CompareValidator ID="id" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="controltovalidateid"
  ErrorMessage="Invalid Date"
  Type="Date" />
```

To limit the users options I've used the calendar control in the ASP.NET.  One nice thing about that control is you can set the date format in the attribute:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
  TargetControlID="Date1"
  CssClass="ClassName"
  Format="dd/mm/yyyy"
  PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

**Other information**

- [AJAX Control Toolkit Download](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit)
- [Calendar Control: AJAX Control Toolkit sample](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)
- [Compare Validator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_comparevalidator.asp)